# TestNG not running in testsuite while encounter error

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to run a testing suite using XML and TestNG, I'm not sure what the root cause of this error happening as i do some research about how to configure the testng.xml but seems but not working for me as I'm always getting the same error as below : Can anyone please tell me where exactly am I going wrong? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Cannot find class in classpath: src/test/java.Login
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:546)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
```

My testng.xml :

```
<suite name="TEST-SUITE" verbose="10"> 
  <test name="YSCBBB AUTOMATION">
    <classes>
      <class name="src/test/java.Login"> 
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

My directory structure in eclipse : 
[image]

Comment: please try this.. `<class name="Login"></class>`

Comment: @4M01 Hi , its not working

Comment: Rename your default package  as - `jayden` for time being and then try 
'<class name="jayden.Login"></class>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had change the code and the structure and its working .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="YSCBBB TEST-SUITE" verbose="1">
    <test name="Regression Suite">
        <classes>
            <!-- <class name="testCases.Login" /> -->
            <class name="testCases.Request_Deposit_OnlinePayment" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_Deposit_ThirdParty" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_Deposit_Wechat" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_Deposit" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_DepositManually" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_DrawBackDealer" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_OpenLottery" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_RebetCredit" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_RetreatTicket" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_RetreatTicketNumberChase" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_TurningPoint" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_Withdraw" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_WithdrawManually" />
            <class name="testCases.Request_BettingNumberChase" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: yet i rename the default package to testCases

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Answer (score -1):

Please try to give the below path in the testng xml file:

```
<class name="src/test/java/testCases/Login">
```

Hope this helps.